# Numpy/Scipy with Openblas

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, python-2.7, numpy

I've been trying to install Numpy/Scipy and allow them to both use Openblas. I've been following various guides but have been using this [one](http://gromgull.net/blog/2013/07/multithreaded-scipynumpy-with-openblas-on-debian/) of late. At the end of the guide, there are a couple of tests to check the speed up of Numpy/Scipy. The tests are:

```
import numpy
import sys
import timeit

try:
    import numpy.core._dotblas
    print 'FAST BLAS'
except ImportError:
    print 'slow blas'

print "version:", numpy.__version__
print "maxint:", sys.maxint
print

x = numpy.random.random((1000,1000))

setup = "import numpy; x = numpy.random.random((1000,1000))"
count = 5

t = timeit.Timer("numpy.dot(x, x.T)", setup=setup)
print "dot:", t.timeit(count)/count, "sec"


import timeit

setup = "import numpy;\
        import scipy.linalg as linalg;\
        x = numpy.random.random((1000,1000));\
        z = numpy.dot(x, x.T)"
count = 5

t = timeit.Timer("linalg.cholesky(z, lower=True)", setup=setup)
print "cholesky:", t.timeit(count)/count, "sec"

t = timeit.Timer("linalg.svd(z)", setup=setup)
print "svd:", t.timeit(count)/count, "sec"
```

My test results show that `slow blas` is being used. However my test results are in line with the guide's test results. My feeling is that openblas is being used by both Numpy/Scipy but `slow blas` is being printed because `numpy.core` doesn't have the `_dotblas` file (which it doesn't). How I can further tell whether openblas is actually being used?

Guide's test results:

```
NumPy
dot: 0.0569217920303 sec

SciPy
cholesky: 0.0204758167267 sec
svd: 0.81153883934 sec
```

My test results:

```
slow blas
version: 1.10.0.dev0+a419ebb
maxint: 9223372036854775807

dot: 0.0185512065887 sec
cholesky: 0.0125649929047 sec
svd: 0.293599033356 sec
```